# How to Store data in DB as decimal precision 4.2

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I am new to JS and HTML and I have a form. In the input fields I get number (%). I need to store it as "`have a precision of decimal (4,2)`". Is there a solution using HTML? This is want I'm trying to do:

1. If the number is 1 to store it as 1.00.
2. If the number is 1.23 store as it is.
3. If the number is 1.12345 store as 1.12
4. If the number is 1.2 store as 1.20
5. If the number is empty store 0.00

In the value I display the value from the DB, and 0.00 if nothing in DB. However the problem is when I press save and it sent to the DB. Is there a solution?
I am using MySQL DB Using laravel

[image]

```html
<div class="d-flex" style="display: flex;">
    <input type="number" name="fee_ctv_omp_percent" id="fee_ctv['omp_percent']" value="{{$fee_ctv['omp_percent'] ?? '0.00'}}" class="w-100"  step="0.1"  max="100" style="border:none;">
    <span class="table-control-addon-right">%</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Your third sample appears wrong. I’m not seeing any JS or PHP, why is this tagged with those? Please show your database info, how you are inserting and querying, along with how you are rendering.

Comment: I fixed the example and I am using mySQL